# Temporarily destroy part of the 2D ground in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to recreate the old game Lode Runner in Unity for practice (I'm fairly new to Unity) and old time's sake and I have no idea of how to achieve this.
There are several assets out there for destructible environment, but it won't do because there's no way (that I know of) of reconstructing it again during gameplay.

So, does anyone know how to temporarily hide/delete/destroy some part of the ground (a perfect square to be exact), changing the colliders as well, and then after certain time make it reappear using C#? or is there some free asset I'm missing?

You can play a clone of a clone here: http://kids-loderunner.appspot.com/loderunner/load-manor-orkut.htm

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to "dig" left or right of the character and after a while recreate the digged tile.

For that, you can have a Grid object with a script called GridManager. and have every tile in the game represented by a 2D GameObject array. so for example if the player is currently in the (10,4) tile and presses the 'z' button to dig left, you can get the tile represented by the game object at tile[9][4] and disable that object.

After a while, the GridManager should reenable the tile in the update function.

Comment: Grids! Why didn't I thought of that? Just about an hour before posting I saw some asset about grids... Thank you, I will research how to use them! n.n
I would upvote you but I need 15rep, sorry about that, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to hide the game object, try below snippet:

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

Refer to [this link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) for more details.

Comment: I was thinking about part of the object, not the object itself, as I was using (wrongly) one image for the whole ground in the level.